# How to Shuffle div on each new page visit

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have code to shuffle my div on reload, but I want to instead have it shuffle on each new page visit. I am no pro in jquery/javascript so came here to ask for some advice.

Here's my code

```js
onload = function() {
  var parent = document.getElementById("shuffle");
  var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
  while (parent.children.length) {
    frag.appendChild(parent.children[Math.floor(Math.random() * parent.children.length)]);
  }
  parent.appendChild(frag);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  window.location.href = window.location.href;
});
```

```css
#shuffle>div {
  float: left;
  line-height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: steelblue;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 3px;
}

#shuffle {
  max-width: 360px;
}
```

```html
<div id="shuffle">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
  <div>12</div>
  <div>13</div>
  <div>14</div>
  <div>15</div>
  <div>16</div>
  <div>17</div>
  <div>18</div>
  <div>19</div>
  <div>20</div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dijesetdesigns/r3tp29gk/4/)

***EDIT - SOLVED***
For anyone who would like to know how this was solved here's the updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dijesetdesigns/nqz5416j/6/)

Comment: `window.location.href = window.location.href;` - what do you *think* this does, what are you trying to do with this line? Also, your posted JS Fiddle demo didn't include the jQuery library, causing its own error.

Comment: Like I said I am not a pro in jquery/javascript. I thought this code reloads the div, but clearly I dont know what I am doing. I got all my code online for the shuffle. I have searched for the solution but cant find one. Hence the reason I am on here. And didnt want to come in here without me having tried something. I think I have a valid question.

Comment: I wasn't challenging the validity of your question - it's certainly valid! - but I was trying to work out what you wanted to achieve with that line, in order to find out what you're trying to do over all. Currently your code shuffles the `<div>` elements on page-load, so it seems like it's already working. Did you want the elements to re-shuffle in response to a user-event or time-out?

Comment: I would like it to shuffle on each new page visit. currently it only shuffles when I refresh the page. So would like it to be shuffled differently for each person that visits. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I managed to get it to work.

Comment: Yes, removing the `$(document).ready(function(){...});` part should turn it into a functioning snippet. You clearly did not use jQuery in it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the problem of your code, but you can use this instead:

```html
<div id="shuffle">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```js
// Function to shuffle children
function shuffleChildren(container){
    let children = container.children();
    while (children.length)
        container.append(children.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * children.length), 1)[0]);
}

// Call the shuffle function on your specific container
shuffleChildren($("#shuffle"));
```